# How to use multiple mongodb databases in one spring boot application and configure it in single yml file

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, database-connection

In my spring boot application, i need to include two mongo databases and use each database for different MongoRepository.
Currently i have configured my mongodb configuration in a yml file. I need to add the other database configuration to this same yml file and specify the using database in each repository.

the yml file :

```
spring:
  data:
mongodb:
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 27017
  database: db_admin_crm
  rest:
  base-path: /crm
```

The repository :

```
 @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "webinarSignups",path = "webinarSignups")
 public interface WebinarSignupsRepository extends MongoRepository<WebinarSignUp,String> {

}
```

Ideas will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: checkout https://dzone.com/articles/multiple-mongodb-connectors-with-spring-boot

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom configuration similar to:

```
first:
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 27017
  database: first

second:
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 27018
  database: second
```

And use this properties in a custom configuration file

```
@Configuration 
public class MongoConfiguration {

    @Value("${first.host}")
    private String firstHost;

    ...

    @Bean(name = "firstMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate firstMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
       // Return a MongoTemplate created using the first properties

       ...
    }

}
```

and use it as follow:

```
@Repository
public class FirstMongoRepository {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("firstMongoTemplate")
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;



    ...
}
```

Note that this approach can be used for any configuration that needs multiple objects of the same type, for example multiple `DataSource` (if you have multiple databases), multiple `ObjectMapper` (if you need distinct kind of serialization)...

Comment: I updated the question. is there a way to do this without using the MongoTemplate?

Comment: @GeekySelene you can do it with any Mongo class related, for example You can use `MongoClient` or `DB`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I set up the configuration but i run into a exception when I try to send GET request to the REST endpoint. Please see here. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56041911/couldnt-find-persistententity-for-type-class-exception-in-spring-boot-mongore