# 'Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class' exception in Spring boot MongoRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, multiple-databases, mongorepository

In here I have configured two databases in mongodb. As described in this tutorial ([link](https://blog.marcosbarbero.com/multiple-mongodb-connectors-in-spring-boot/)). So basically I override the `MongoDataAutoConfiguration` and `MongoProperties` implementations.

The property yml file :

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
       exclude: 
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration

mongodb:
   primary:
     host: 127.0.0.1
     port: 27017
     database: db_admin_crm
   secondary:
     host: 127.0.0.1
     port: 27017
     database: lead_forms
```

MultipleMongoProperties class :

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mongodb")
public class MultipleMongoProperties {

 private MongoProperties primary = new MongoProperties();
 private MongoProperties secondary = new MongoProperties();
    //getters and setters
}
```

MultipleMongoConfig class :

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MultipleMongoProperties.class)
public class MultipleMongoConfig {

@Autowired
private final MultipleMongoProperties mongoProperties;

public MultipleMongoConfig() {
    mongoProperties = null;
}


@Primary
@Bean(name = "primaryMongoTemplate")
public MongoTemplate primaryMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(primaryFactory(this.mongoProperties.getPrimary()));
}

@Bean(name = "secondaryMongoTemplate")
public MongoTemplate secondaryMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(secondaryFactory(this.mongoProperties.getSecondary()));
}

@Bean
@Primary
public MongoDbFactory primaryFactory(final MongoProperties mongo) throws Exception {
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(mongo.getHost(), mongo.getPort()),
            mongo.getDatabase());
}

@Bean
public MongoDbFactory secondaryFactory(final MongoProperties mongo) throws Exception {
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(mongo.getHost(), mongo.getPort()),
            mongo.getDatabase());
  }
}
```

PrimaryMongoConfig :

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "io.crm.service.repositories",
    mongoTemplateRef = "primaryMongoTemplate")
public class PrimaryMongoConfig{
}
```

SecondaryMongoConfig :

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "io.crm.service.repositories.report.repositories",
    mongoTemplateRef = "secondaryMongoTemplate")
public class SecondaryMongoConfig {
}
```

The Repository class :

```
   @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users",path = "users",excerptProjection = UserProjection.class)
   public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

 }
```

User model class :

```
@Id
private String id;
private String email;
private String name;
private String businessName;
private String phone;
private String address;
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
private Date createdTime;
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
private Date updatedTime;
@Field("bookletSignUps")
@DBRef
private List<BookletSignUp> bookletSignUps;
@Field("eventSignUps")
@DBRef
private List<EventSignUp> eventSignUps;
@Field("infoSignUps")
@DBRef
private List<InfoSignUp> infoSignUps;
@Field("webinarSignUps")
@DBRef
private List<WebinarSignUp> webinarSignUps;
```

The projection :

```
@Projection(name = "userExcerpt", types = User.class)
public interface UserProjection {

String getId();
String getName();
String getEmail();
String getBusinessName();
String getPhone();
String getAddress();
Date getCreatedTime();
Date getUpdatedTime();
List<BookletSignUp> getBookletSignUps();
List<EventSignUp> getEventSignUps();
List<InfoSignUp> getInfoSignUps();
List<WebinarSignUp> getWebinarSignUps();

}
```

But when im trying to do a GET request to the REST endpoint `http://localhost:9090/users/` im getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class io.crm.service.models.User!` exception here. What could be gone wrong here? Ideas will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the User class code

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO added.

Comment: I think that the problem is that spring is not scanning your packages to find the entities definitions. Probably using a custom configuration will change the default behaviour and you need to manually configure something more, but I have no direct experience on that so I can't go deeper on that analysis

Comment: As you could observe there is no issue in the current implementation upto now?

Comment: Is User class serializable and annotated with @Document ?

Comment: yes with these annotations. 
Data
AllArgsConstructor
NoArgsConstructor
Document(collection = "user")'

Comment: Hey @GeekySelene , did you found the answer for this, i am struggling from last 3 days. Same issue arised when i configured 2 mongodb in spring application.